# How to create multipage report for single record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have to create multipage report e.g. 3-10 legal size pages based on the static texts that I add in the report through label/textbox control.In fact all of 3-10 pages contain mostly static text except some field-data from the single record of Access table. Table data is located all over the static text.

I have tried page break. There is a limitation of page length to 22 inches while 10 legal pages length amounts to almost 140 inches.

Is it possible in MS Access 2016?

Comment: If the limitation is only for design view, you could try moving the static pages into subreports with `Can Grow = Yes`.

Comment: Did you consider using eg Word in combination with the mail-merge (to pull data from your database) if you have so much static text? Just an idea. • Alternatively use more sections, the 22 inch limit is per section not per report.

Comment: @Andre field-data or calculated value of field-data is distribute all over the static texts.So I can not isolate static part.

Comment: @PEH I do not want to switch to another technology since that will involve cost,user-trainig...

Comment: @SIslam well as always google helps: [How to create multi-page reports in Access?](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-to-create-multi-page-reports-in-access.2140585)

Comment: Allen Browne to the rescue! I did not know that the limit is per section. @Pᴇʜ

Comment: @PEH Another help https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3268/How-to-Create-Multiple-Detail-Sections-on-Reports.html.   but this aproach is not neat - suppose when real grouping is needed.

Comment: @SIslam well workarounds are never neat, otherwise they won't be workarounds. Neat would be to respect the limit and use another tool that is capable to do it correctly :) But since that is no option for you, you will have to choose one of the ugly workarounds.